# Spring Catch JpaSystemException in @Transactional Method and Roll Back Transaction

Tags: java, spring, error-handling, transactional

I have a method that is annotated with

```
@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
```

and calls several repository methods. Now when one repository tries to alter a DB-row that is locked and not rolled back by another instance of the method, spring correctly throws

```
 org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not execute statement [...] Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: transaction could not be serialized and rolls back the failed transaction.
```

Now I want to keep all this behaviour but additionally handle the exception and start a retry. Here's a code snippet:

```
@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    @Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
    public void messageReceived(Card card) {
        this.request = request;
        this.numberOfAttempts = reset ? 0 : this.numberOfAttempts++;
        this.reset = true;
        LOGGER.info("Message received from Queue: " + card);
        TransactionDebugUtils.transactionRequired("MessageReceivedController.messageReceived");

        try {
            [...]
            repository1.createKonto(card);
            repository2.doStuff(card);

        } catch (JpaSystemException e) {
            //This is obviously never invoked
            LOGGER.error("TRANSACTION FAILED!!!");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error mapping json request to data model", message, e);
        }
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(JpaSystemException.class)
    //This is also never invoked
    public void handleJpaSystemException(JpaSystemException ex) {
        this.messageReceived(this.request);
        this.reset = false;
    }
```

Comment: I found out I can catch the Exception outside the controller. Is that the only way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this issue recently. As it is a method level @Transactional annotation, Transaction commit occurs after finishing method execution. 
When you are using this annotation 2 concepts should be considered

1. persistence context
2. database transaction

After messageReceived() method is executed, those 2 things will happen and JPA exception is thrown at @Transactional level which means you need to handle this exception from where you are calling this method(controller; if you are calling from a controller).
More regarding @Transactional can be found in this [link](http://www.codingpedia.org/jhadesdev/how-does-spring-transactional-really-work/).